# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:

```
SELECT r.CALLID  AS MultiRES,
c.CallDate AS CallDate,
cr.Institution AS Institution,
cr.Branch AS Branch
FROM tblResolution r
INNER JOIN tblcall c ON c.CallID=c.CallID AND c.CallDate=c.CallDate
INNER JOIN tblCaller cr ON cr.Institution = cr.Institution AND cr.Branch=cr.Branch
GROUP BY r.CALLID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

But I get an error when I run it, I know I need to do something with a group by clause, I just don't know where to put it.

EDIT: Just figured out what was wrong:

```
SELECT r.CALLID  AS MultiRES,
c.CallDate AS CallDate,
cr.Institution AS Institution,
cr.Branch AS Branch
FROM tblResolution r
INNER JOIN tblcall c ON c.CallID=c.CallID AND c.CallDate=c.CallDate
INNER JOIN tblCaller cr ON cr.Institution = cr.Institution AND cr.Branch=cr.Branch
GROUP BY c.CallDate,cr.Institution,cr.Branch, r.CALLID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: First, you don't need a `GROUP BY`, because you're not aggregating anything (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG`) in your `SELECT`. Second, every column that is not being aggregated has to be in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @KenWhite: But they *are* aggregating something in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in the select clause needs to be in the group by clause unless it is an aggregate function (e.g. `count` or `sum`):

```
SELECT r.CALLID  AS MultiRES,
c.CallDate AS CallDate,
cr.Institution AS Institution,
cr.Branch AS Branch
FROM tblResolution r
INNER JOIN tblcall c ON c.CallID=c.CallID AND c.CallDate=c.CallDate
INNER JOIN tblCaller cr ON cr.Institution = cr.Institution AND cr.Branch=cr.Branch
GROUP BY r.CALLID, c.CallDate, cr.Institution, cr.Branch
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Now I'm getting multiple results of the same column, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What do you want to see as a result?  By selecting and grouping by 4 columns each row will be a unique combination of them.

Comment: I'm getting duplicate values for each record.

Comment: @user1319343: Grouping guarantees that the columns you are grouping by make up distinct *combinations* in the output. What are you trying to achieve actually? Obtain distinct values of *every* column? If so, how would you decide on which values should go on the same row with which else values? Maybe you need to issue 4 different queries to get 4 distinct lists of values, one per every column you are interested in.